# Ruby + MySQL error connecting to database on localhost

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm dealing with this a few days, and cannot connect to a simple mysql database on localhost.

```
require "mysql"

@db_host = "localhost"
@db_user = "myrubyapp"
@db_pass = "1234"
@db_name = "myrubyapp"

mysql = Mysql.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
```

The output I got is an error: `can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)` where `Mysql.new` is.

The second one, I tried to change the gem to mysql2

```
require "mysql2"

@db_host = "localhost"
@db_user = "myrubyapp"
@db_pass = "1234"
@db_name = "myrubyapp"

mysql = Mysql2.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
```

The output is an error too, but is different from the first: `undefined method "new" for Mysql2:Module (NoMethodError)`.

Guys I'm sorry that I have to ask this kind of questions, but I'm really really confused, I have an experience of programming more than 3 years in JavaSE and EE, I am ashamed cause I can't deal with that. Please point me into right direction and don't judge me harshly. I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
```

Comment: `Can't connect to MySQL server on "localhost" (10061) (Mysql2::Error)` I tried to put instead of localhost - `127.0.0.1` and it connects, but why?

Comment: Maybe because localhost is not getting resolved to 127.0.0.1 or you have a firewall whose ports have been opened only for 127.0.0.1. What OS are you using? If Linux or OSX variants, do you see "127.0.0.1 localhost" or "127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain      localhost" in the /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 2):

correct syntax is:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
```

see [mysql2 on github](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#usage) for more examples

I recomment you to take a look at [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) as raw mysql2 lib provide a very limited functionality and Sequel can do a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and for advice, I'll try as an alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Never used the gem mysql, but have you tried to remove the hash :host => etc and pass directly a list of parameters?
Something like `con = Mysql.new db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name`
http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/ for a tutorial